# How to add methods to PropertyChangedEventHandler that is inherited

Tags: c#, inheritance, inotifypropertychanged

I'm trying to add methods to a PropertyChangedEventHandler that is contained in a parent class. It can see the inherited event, and it doesn't throw an exception, but when running the event raiser it doesn't show as having added events.

Parent Class (both of these are seen, but PropertyChanged won't keep additions)

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the PropertyChanged event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Name of the Property that was changed</param>
    /// <param name="passThroughSender">Optional reference to another sender if this instance is not intended to be the sender</param>
    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName, object passThroughSender = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(passThroughSender ?? this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Inheriting class (it inherits and sees both properties)

```
public class VMViewPage : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged, IHandleCleanup
    {
        ...
    }
```

Subscribing class contstructor (it hits the property changed, but doesn't add or throw an exception.)

```
        VMViewPage parentContext = BoundWindow.DataContext as VMViewPage;
        parentContext.PropertyChanged += VersionPropertyChanged;
```

Subscribing class event raiser (it hits and calls the raiser, but doesn't do anything because it never added properly)

```
    public string VersionID
    {
        get { return (_versionID); }
        private set { _versionID = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("VersionID", this); }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what's going on here - I don't even know how many classes you've got. It looks like you're expecting `parentContext` to know about the fact that you're calling `NotifyPropertyChanged` in a different class, which isn't how it works. Please give a short but *complete* example which demonstrates the problem. (Just a simple console app, ideally.)

Comment: actually, this perfectly answered my question. I made a simple mistake, the third class also inherited the parent and so it was calling the NotifyPropertyChanged and using to a null handle because it was it's own rather than the one it had subscribed to. Thanks